# Conditional PHP for IE to direct to different site?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I am pretty new to php so bear with me :)

I am trying to create a web page that can use the `get_user_browser` function in php to then direct the user to a separate HTML page.

My website is http://www.danabohne.com and I just realized it is barely visible in IE. Unless there's a different way to go around this I want to make a separate static HTML site that can be seen by IE users.

Any feedback would be extremely helpful!

Comment: You really should fix your issues as there is no reason for your site to not work i n IE much less have two different websites just because of a browser issue.

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with -- If it's barely visible in IE8, then a bit of work may be in order, but if it's in IE6 then it really doesn't matter, unless you have a specific reason to support old browsers.

Comment: I don't think this question is very constructive. Redirects are extensively covered on stackoverflow, and hacking around IE isn't going to give other readers good advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];  
if( strpos($useragent,"MSIE 6.0") ) { 

  header("Location: http://google.com"); 

}
?>
```

You can add more `if` conditions as needed.

However , Like John mentioned in the comments. I would advise you to create a separate stylesheet and create a fallback design  rather than redirecting to another page.

Comment: @Dana, _Don't_ use the `strpos()` method! Take advice from Spudley's answer, and deal with any IE-specific issues with a [conditional stylesheet](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: @JamWaffles  That's what i told at the end of my answer as well. Conditional Stylesheet and fallbacks are best.  But i guess she doesn't want to do that much work.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's important to note that browser detection on the server is not recommended, because it is possible for browsers to provide false user agent details, or none at all. (I know of some firewall products that routinely strip out this kind of data from the http headers).

Secondly, the `get_user_browser` function only works if you have a valid `browsecap.ini` file. If you're having trouble getting the function to work, check that you have this ini file and that it is up-to-date. (also note that you will need to keep it updated whenever new browsers or browser versions are released).

Finally, most (virtually all) IE-specific display issues can be resolved without having to create a separate page for IE.

Specifically in your case, I can see what the problem is straight away when looking at the HTML source code for your page:

The problem is the `<pre></pre>` that is in the first line of your code immediately before the `<!DOCTYPE>`. I assume this is the left-overs from some debugging code that hasn't been removed properly.

This `<pre></pre>` is going to cause IE to fall into "quirks mode", because IE sees the `<pre>` and assumes it doesn't have a doctype. Without a doctype, IE assumes the page should be in quirks mode.

Quirks mode makes IE's rendering engine display the page completely differently (it's basically an IE5-backward-compatibility mode), so it's no wonder your page looks rubbish in IE.

This behaviour is the same in all versions of IE.

If you have other IE-specific problems, it would be better to try to fix them on the page, as there are a lot of tools and hacks available to make IE work better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good spot @Spudley. :)  .  `<pre></pre>`  will indeed trigger quirks mode.